# ScrollView did not move up when click textfield inside tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview, textfield

I tried this code :
in viewWillAppear :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillDisappear), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

and :

```
@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("keyboard appear")
    var info = notification.userInfo
    let keyBoardSize = info![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    scrollCreateEditContact.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyBoardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollCreateEditContact.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyBoardSize.height, 0.0)
}

@objc func keyboardWillDisappear(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("keyboard disappear")
    scrollCreateEditContact.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollCreateEditContact.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

and result is :
[image]

what I want is that textfield did not covered by keyboard when keyboard appear like this :

[image]

That code only work on textfield that is not inside tableView.
But when I click textfield inside tableView and log it "keyboard appear" always detected.

What is the correct code for textfield inside tableView not covered by keyboard when keyboard appear?

Comment: Why don't you use IQkeyboardManager pod library, It's very easy with it to handle the keyboard.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger How to use it?

Comment: Just install pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' and in your appDelegate.swift file in did finish launching add following line:              IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

Comment: we used to have lot's of problem manually handling it then we moved to IQKeyboardManager it's great Pod library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easiest way to handle this problem is installing pod for IQKeyboardManager:**

Installation via cocoa pods:

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

Usage:

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

      return true
    }
}
```

For more information on IQKeyboardManager refer this link:

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger great answer with sample how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Thats common behaviour, ios cannot adjust content above keyboard automatically, unlike android. My solution is, you can wrap all that views (photo, textfield, etc) inside tableView. And use `TPKeyboardAvoiding` library.

```
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
```

If you use storyboard, set tableView base-class to `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the most common and used libraries for managing such behavior:

1. **[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)**
2. **[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)**

You can install them via CocoaPods as well.