# View Responsiveness on Keyboard Show and Hide Ios Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikeyboard

This is my view.

[image]

When I click inside the text view the keyboard was coming on top. so I added made a class and in that class, I added these functions.

```
    var objectObserver:UIViewController?

    func setKeyboardResponsiviness(observer:UIViewController){
            objectObserver = observer
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                if objectObserver!.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                    objectObserver!.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                }
            }
        }

        @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            if objectObserver!.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
                objectObserver!.view.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
        }
```

After adding the code the whole screen slides up which was the intended goal but as a side effect, half of the text view is out of the screen. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: you can do this easily with IQKeyboardManager pod library

Comment: you can refer to this stack answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/54288261/3278326

Comment: thanks man post as answer so i can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to use IQKeyboardManagerSwift.

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' // add this in your pod file.
```

Add the following code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
```

I hope this helps.